# forms showing in runtime as soon as they are created

Tags: forms, delphi

In runtime when the forms are being created, 2 forms constantly keep appearing when I haven't programmed them to show as soon as they are created, and my system runs. I was wondering why this happened and whether there is anything to solve this? I don't think I need to show my code here since it's pretty basic and there is none for the OnCreate event.

Answer (score 2):

From the main menu, use **Project->Options->Forms**, and remove the forms you don't want to see from the **Auto-create** list. (Click the **>>** button to move them from the left side to the right side.)

(It's worth mentioning that you can also affect the order in which any autocreated forms or datamodules are created from that dialog by just dragging them up or down in the list. Note that the first form to be created becomes the application main form, so when it is closed the application will close as well; this means that the only thing above your main form in the autocreate list should be datamodule(s) that are accessed by the main form.)

If you never want any forms auto-created, go to **Tools->Options->Environment Options->Form Designer**, and uncheck the very last item labeled **Auto create forms & data modules** at the bottom. Note that your main form will always be auto-created, as it's what controls the application's lifetime for form based applications.

Comment: +1 Didn't know you could turn off this extra-ordinarily stoopid mis-feature, just learnt to cope with it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson it was driving me crazy! and just looked like I'd done sone crazy code that I couldn't find

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks ill try doing that tomorrow

Comment: @user129092 You'll find this mis-feature the answer to a fair few delphi questions on here. At least you are starting right, I had to work on apps where someone "thought" this was a good idea and made extensive use of it.

Comment: @Tony: Datamodules have a useful place. They're great containers for non-visual components like imagelists and data access components like connections and queries, because it keeps clutter off your forms. They also help separate data from your UI. They can also be created before any form (including the main form) to make those things available when the main form loads, without interfering with the normal function of the main form.

Comment: Oh I know what they are for. So you can create all your global variables at design time and bind to them...

Comment: @Tony: Well, that's extreme. If you have images that are used in toolbars across multiple forms, for instance, it's much better to have them in a single TImageList in a datamodule and share it than it is to have many different imagelists scattered through your app, especially when you decide to update your application later. Taking a very limited view of something is frequently a poor idea in programming (or life in general). :-) It doesn't have to be at designtime, either. I often put something non-visual in a DM that I refer to only in code and never "bind to" at designtime.

Comment: @KenWhite You and I are exceptions in my bitter experience. Most simply moved the db components from their form onto a db module, and then 're-use' them everywhere, often making use of that fun BookMark thing and the Disable / Enable Controls methods.

Comment: An easier way to fix my problem was to uncheck Visible of the form

Answer (score 0):

By default delphi creates all the forms in the beginning. You can open the .dpr file and delete the ones that you don't need. You could also do that from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

For the forms that you don't want to appear at the start of runtime, go to the properties of the form (lower left hand side) and uncheck `Visible`. This should do the trick

Comment: @KenWhite ok ill try that. Would I have to change it back to Visible = true?

Comment: @mghie I want them to be created just not visible until I press the button to make it visible :)

Comment: @user129092: Well, I hope Ken removes the down vote then. And you might want to edit your question to make this point clearer.

Comment: @mghie: Done. Regarding your "not be leaked" - it will if the forms are autocreated and then created again in code (which I thought the post was asking about, and thus the answer I wrote) if the same global var is used without first freeing the autocreated form. IE: Allow `Form2` to autocreate with `Visible` false. In the `TForm1.FormCreate` use `Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);` You've leaked the original autocreated form in `Form2`.)

Comment: @KenWhite: I don't think that is true, as the form creation in the way you show it will add the forms to a list of owned components, so that either the owner form or the application object will free them. One would have to pass `nil` to the constructor to circumvent that. Or do I miss something here?

Comment: @mghie: The application will try to free them *when the app closes*, but the content of that pointer has been replaced by the form you create at runtime. One of them remains in memory the entire time your app is running, but you have absolutely no way to access it or use it. Repeat that with a few forms (or even one that has a page control with multiple tabs with many controls per tab), and it's a substantial leak. The application won't free it at runtime, because `FreeNotification` is only called when the object is being freed, and the leaked form isn't being freed.

Comment: @KenWhite Is that why when i view the file in an exe format, the details are saved slightly incorrectly?

Comment: @user129092: Is *what* why? I said nothing about viewing the file in "an .exe format", so I have no idea what you're asking. What part of my comments are you asking about, and can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: @KenWhite What I meant is, I view my file in an exe format separately, and though the record details such as name, DOB etc can be viewed correctly in the system, when I actually view the file it isn't. Is that in any way linked to your comments regarding memory leaks?

Comment: The question here is about *form creation* and visibility. What in the world do "record details", "name, DOB etc", and "exe format" (which I'm guessing means "in binary form") have to do with it? What is in the binary representation of a data file has nothing to do with memory management or leaks, all of which are related to *code*.